# $\forall x\forall y(x<y \to y\not<x)\iff \forall x\forall y((x\le y \text{ and } x\neq y)\to (y\not\leq x\text{ or }x=y))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This is how I got this equivalence:

$$x < y → y≮x ↔ $$

$$x < y → ~(y < x) ↔ $$

$$(x≤y ∧ x≠y) → ~(y≤x ∧ x≠y) ↔$$

$$(x≤y ∧ x≠y) → (~y≤x ∨ ~x≠y) ↔$$

$$(x≤y ∧ x≠y) → (y≰x ∨ x=y)$$

I would like to know if this is correct

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: $(x\lt y \to y \not\lt x) \leftrightarrow  (x\lt y \to y \geq x)$.  Your first step is quite incorrect.  You are claiming that $(x\lt y)$ implies both $y\not\lt x$ and $y \lt x$.

Comment: @amWhy yeah my bad, I mistyped it, i checked my notebook and I forgot to put the symbol ¬ in front of (y<x) $$(x<y→y≮x) ↔ (x<y→¬(y<x))$$